# Flutter Web - Save ui.Image to png File

Tags: flutter, image, flutter-web

I need some help with my code, I use the

> "FilePicker.platform.saveFile()"

function to get the path on Windows Version (but not works on Web) and then

```
"final imageFuture = await controller
          .renderImage(backgroundImageSize)
          .then<Uint8List?>((ui.Image image) => image.pngBytes);
final imgFile = File(path);
imgFile.writeAsBytesSync(imageFuture!);
"
```

to save my image to disk, this works perfectly on Windows, but not on the web version.
**I need an alternative to save ui.Image (web Version) to PNG File on disk.**

Comment: you cannot - your browser does not have an access to the filesystem

Comment: Unfortunately I know that the web does not have this access, but the question would be if there is any alternative for this, I need to save this ui.Image on disk

Comment: You will have to save to an external service in the cloud using an API. You can try something like the AWS SDK for JavaScript.

Comment: I was reading something about using only javascript functions for this, without needing an external service, I tested it, but it doesn't save the whole image, do you know anything about javascript functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem only, however the solution works only in release mode (after the build process).

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'dart:js' as js;

final backgroundImageSize = Size(backgroundImage!.width.toDouble(),
          backgroundImage!.height.toDouble());
      final imageFuture = await controller
          .renderImage(backgroundImageSize)
          .then<Uint8List?>((ui.Image image) => image.pngBytes);
(imageFuture != null)
        ? js.context.callMethod(
            "saveAs",
            [
              html.Blob([imageFuture]),
              'output-image.png',
            ],
          )
        : print('Image is null');
```

It is necessary to add inside your web/index.html file:

```
<script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/amcharts/3.21.15/plugins/export/libs/FileSaver.js/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
```